# InvalidPathException: No action config found for the specified url

Tags: ajax, datatables, struts

I am getting below error as Ajax call response. 
Below is the response body for Ajax call.

> Apache Tomcat/7.0.61 - Error report
>
> ## HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.struts.chain.commands.InvalidPathException: No action config found for the specified url.
>
> **type** Status report
>
> **message** org.apache.struts.chain.commands.InvalidPathException: No action config found for the specified url.
>
> **description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> #### Apache Tomcat/7.0.61

Is it something to do with JRE 7?
Here is the JavaScript code from my JSP file. 
I have defined a table in my JSP file which is referenced here.

```
function showLogHistory() {

    var questionId = document.getElementById('txtQuestionId').innerHTML;

    var url = "myAction.do?dispatchMethodName=showmyAudit&questionId="+questionId;

    if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tblmyAudit') ) {
        $('#tblmyAudit').DataTable().destroy();
    }

    $('#tblmyAudit').DataTable( {

        "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
                $("#tblmyAudit tbody tr.data-in-table").each(function () {
                var i=0;
                    $(this).find('td').each(function (index) {
                        var currentCell = $(this);
                        var nextCell = 
                           $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('td').eq(i).length > 0 ?
                           $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('td').eq(i) : null;
                        if ( currentCell.text() !== nextCell.text()) {
                            currentCell.css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
                        }
                        i=i+1;
                    });
                });

        },

        "ajax": {
            "url": url,
            "cache": true
        },

        "columns": [
                { "data": "questionId" },

                { "data": "Category" },
                { "data": "Area" },

                { "data": "question" },
                { "data": "answer" },

                { "data": "updated_by" },
                { "data": "updated_date" }

            ],

        "scrollX": true,

        "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": [ '_all' ],
                "orderable": false
        } ],

        "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
              $(row).addClass( 'data-in-table' );
          }
    } );

    $('#detmyAudit').modal('show');
}
```

URL that gets generated for Ajax seems proper.

Comment: Without seeing the actual request URL (e.g., from your network console) and the associated action mapping, there's zero way to help.

Comment: How could we know what is with JRE on your server.

Comment: there was typo in the action name in my URL. It's resolved now. Thanks.